Using substitution to find the integral of a product between an affine and a radical
Let's say we have a function that is a product between an affine function, say $x$, and a radical function, say $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$.
$f(x) = x\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$
How do we find the indefinite integral of $f$ using substitution? I seem to find no reasonable substitutes for $u$ and $dv$.

I highly suggest using trigonometric substitutions for integrals involving radicals.

In the case you have suggested I would simply use the substitution $u=x^2+1$: though it is good to recognise that if we have something where $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is involved, a trigonometric / hyperbolic substitution is good, in the case suggested it is not necessary.

Let $u=\sqrt {x^2+1}$, then $2udu=2xdx$ and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int x \sqrt{x^2+1} d x & =\int u \cdot u d u \\
& =\int u^2 d u \\
& =\frac{u^3}{3}+C \\
& =\frac{\left(x^2+1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Wow, this is astonishingly simple, but a bit too creative. How could one formulaically come up with a solution like this?

@BarackBarackBarack
The first thing you should do when you integrate and use substitution is find a factor whose derivative exists elsewhere in the function. With this principle in mind, $(x^2 + 1)$ easily comes to mind as the first possible $u$ you should try, because its derivative, $2x$, exists elsewhere in the function (at least the important part).

partial HINTS:
With Hyperbolic functions
substitute
$$y=x\sqrt{x^2+1}$$
$$x=\sinh u = sh u$$
$$ \int( y~dx) =\int{sh u~ch u~ch u~du} = \int (sh u+ sh^3 u) du$$
Convert to multiple arguments..
With Trigonometric functions
(left out obvious arguments)
substitute
$$x=\tan u = t , \cos u =c $$
$$ \int( y~dx) =\int{t .sec. sec^2 ~du} = \int \frac{s}{c^4} du$$
Convert to multiple arguments..
